# Nginx magically set PHP_ADMIN_VALUE; Can't get rid of it

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

i'm trying to configure my 3rd webapp on my raspberry.
I accidently pulled a nginx conf for this third site containing following lines:

```
[...]
server {
  [...]
  location ~.php$ {
    [...]
    fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE      "open_basedir=$base/:/usr/lib/php/:/tmp/";
    [...]
  }
}
```

From now on, even my two other apps are complaining with following line:

```
2020/05/06 21:39:55 [error] 21359#21359: *35 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/<1ST_WEBAPP_ROOT>/lib/composer/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/<3RD_WEBAPP_ROOT>/:/usr/lib/php/:/tmp/) in /var/www/<1ST_WEBAPP_ROOT>/lib/base.php on line 504" while reading response header from upstream, client: <IP>, server: <1ST_WEBAPP_URL>, request: "GET /status.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "<1ST_WEBAPP_URL>"
```

I uncommented this line:

```
[...]
server {
  [...]
  location ~.php$ {
    [...]
    #fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE      "open_basedir=$base/:/usr/lib/php/:/tmp/";
    [...]
  }
}
```

stoped, restarted nginx

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

But the error persists. Even removing both server blocks (port 80 and 443) didn't help.
Any suggestions what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found it...

Last step missing was restarting the php-fpm

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php7.3-fpm restart
```

Thank you for reading. Sorry